problem with envrionment variables when creating docker image in ec2 nestjs
In my local environment i made a .env file and used .env file to store my environment variables for oauth2 login and when i built a docker image with it i used docker-compose.yaml file for env variables but when i build it gives me error as such
[Nest] 1  - 07/07/2024, 9:31:03 AM   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] OAuth2Strategy requires a clientID option
TypeError: OAuth2Strategy requires a clientID option
    at GoogleStrategy.OAuth2Strategy (/usr/src/app/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:83:34)
    at new Strategy (/usr/src/app/node_modules/passport-google-oauth20/lib/strategy.js:52:18)
    at new MixinStrategy (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@nestjs/passport/dist/passport/passport.strategy.js:32:13)
    at new GoogleStrategy (/usr/src/app/dist/auth/utils/strategies/google.strategy.js:23:9)
    at Injector.instantiateClass (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:365:19)
    at callback (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:65:45)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Injector.resolveConstructorParams (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:144:24)
    at async Injector.loadInstance (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:70:13)
    at async Injector.loadProvider (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:97:9)

this error
this is my docker-compose.yaml file
version: '3'

services:
  backend:
    build: ./
    container_name: EZCryptoExchange
    environment:
      - GOOGLE_CLIENTID=XXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com
      - GOOGLE_SECRET=XXXXXXXXX
      - APP_PORT=3001
      - GOOGLE_CALLBACK_URL="http://localhost:3001/api/auth/google/redirect"
      - KAKAO_CLIENTID=XXXXXXXXXX
      - KAKAO_SECRET=XXXXXXXXX
      - KAKAO_CALLBACK_URL="http://localhost:3001/api/auth/kakao/redirect"
      - SESSION_SECRET=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
      - KAKAOPAY_SECRET=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    ports:
      -"3001:3001"

this is my google.strategy
@Injectable()
export class GoogleStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {


    constructor(private readonly configService: ConfigService,
                @Inject('AUTH_SERVICE') private readonly authService: AuthService,) {
        super({
            clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENTID,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET,
            callbackURL: process.env.GOOGLE_CALLBACK_URL,
            scope: ['profile', 'email'],
        });    
    }

    async validate(accessToken: string, refreshToken: string, profile: Profile) {
        console.log(profile)
        const user = await this.authService.validateUser({email: profile.emails[0].value, 
                                       displayName:profile.displayName, walletPrivateKey: "1", walletAddress: "1"})

        return user || null; 
    }
}

In my local environment i made a .env file and used .env file to store my environment variables for oauth2 login and when i built a docker image with it i used docker-compose.yaml file for env variables but when i build it gives me error as such

Are you seeing this when you build the image (e.g., docker-compose build) or when you run it (docker-compose up)?  If it's a build issue, what's in your Dockerfile?

This should work when you build it using the docker-compose.yml file, the variables defined in the environment are used when we build the image, you can see that as the equivalent of a .env file inside of your docker-compose file.
If you build this image using the regular docker build command the variables in your .env file in your project's directory won't be available in your container unless you specify it in your Dockerfile and run the build with the correct arguments, here's an example of how to do this:
Export variables to your bash:
source .env
Then use --build-arg flag to pass them to your docker build:
docker image build --build-arg GOOGLE_CLIENTID=$GOOGLE_CLIENTID --build-arg GOOGLE_SECRET=$GOOGLE_SECRET .
Add this in your Dockerfile
ARG GOOGLE_CLIENTID
ARG GOOGLE_SECRET
ENV GOOGLE_CLIENTID=$GOOGLE_CLIENTID
ENV GOOGLE_SECRET=$GOOGLE_SECRET

I used this question as a reference: How can I pass ENV value in Dockerfile from .env file?
P.S.: It's not a good idea to post your third party credentials in a public site, they could be be misused, I'll edit those for you
